# How to generate all legal state-action pairs of connect four?

Tags: python, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, reinforcement-learning

Consider a standard 7*6 board. Suppose I want to apply Q-Learning algorithm. For applying it, I need a set of all possible states and actions. There can be 3^(7*6) = 150094635296999121. Since its not feasible to store these, I am only considering legal states.

How can I generate Q(s,a) for all the legal states and actions?

This is not my homework. I am trying to learn about reinforcement algorithms. I have been searching about this since two days. The closest thing I have come to is consider only the legal states.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 process you need to set up.  One that generates the next move, one that changes where that move leads, and lastly evaluating a block of 4x4 through a series of checks to see if this is a winner .  Numpy and scipy will help with this.

Set up a Numpy array of zeroes.  Change the number to 1 for player 1 moves and -1 for moves done by player 2.  The 4x4 check is summing over the x axis and then the y axis and then the sum of the diagonals if the abs(sum(axis))==4 then yield board earlier than the end.

This may create duplicates depending on the implementation so put all of these in a set at the end.

**Edit due to comments and the question modification.

You need to use generators and do a depth first search. There is a max of 7 possible branches for any state with a possibility of 42 moves.  You are only looking for winning or loosing states to store (don't save stalemates as they take the most memory).  The states will be 2 sets of locations one for each player.
When you step forward and find a winning/losing state, store the state with the value, step backward to the previous move and update the value there storing this as well.

There are 144 possible ways of winning/losing to connect four with I don't know how many states associated with each.  so I'm not sure how many steps away from winning you want to store.

Comment: 1. Done - Next Move is generated by nextMove()
2. Done - New state is returned by applyMove(nextMove())
3. Done - I have a function for vertically, horizontally and diagonally evaluating the board.

But my question is not this. I need all (legal) state-action pairs which is the first step of Q-Learning algorithm. I have edited the question to make my question more clear.